# wmic failure with concurrent calls on XP and Server 2003

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I am using `wmic` to get the time. I have narrowed this down to a one (1) line .bat file. I have learned from stackoverflow about piping stdin and stdout to avoid hangs.

```
C:> type t.bat
TYPE NUL | wmic os get localdatetime | findstr .
```

It seems that if I run wmic concurrently, it will occasionally fail. If I create two cmd shells and run the following command in each, errors similar to the one below appear.

```
for /l %i in (0,1,100) do (call t.bat)
```

...

```
C:> TYPE NUL | wmic os get localdatetime  | findstr .
Win32 Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

This does not appear to happen on Vista, 7, etc. I have only seen it happen on Windows XP SP3 and Windows Server 2003 SP2.

The "file" it is talking about may be `TempWmicBatchFile.bat`, but I do not know that for sure. I have not seen this file appear on the Windows Vista or Windows 7 machines.

Is there another way to get the current time? The `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` variables are formatted in the user's choice of representation, so I cannot use that. Any suggestions?

Comment: i tested this with 5 cmd windows and all worked fine.

Comment: I've worked a lot with WMIC, but I've never heard of "piping stdin and stdout to avoid hangs". Could you provide a link to what you are referring to?

Comment: I used getTimeStamp.bat from dbenham as mentioned below. After purging all uses of wmic.exe, the programs are working.

Comment: I looked again for the pipe in/out messages, but do not find them. I know that I had plenty of difficulty before adding the redirections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of the issue you are reporting.

You could try [getTimeStamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27422) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that provides robust, locale independent, date and time computation and formatting. The utility is pure script using native Windows functionality.

Assuming you have getTimeStamp.bat in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere in your path, then the following will create a variable named currentTimeStamp containing the current date and time in WMIC format.

```
call getTimeStamp -f {yyyy}{mm}{dd}{hh}{nn}{ss}.{fff}000{zzzz} -r currentTimeStamp
```

There are a great many formats available, as well as the ability to apply date and time offsets, etc. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Comment: Dave, I have been using getTimeStamp.bat with some success. What does the line "for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('set -o 2^>nul') do (" accomplish. What does "set -o" report?

Comment: @Paul - It parses the current definition of all the offset parameters (-oy, -om, -od, etc.). See the definition of the offset variable on the line above, which equates the offset type to the partial name of a JScript function. For example, -oh becomes setHours() and getHours(). The -oz parameter is for time zone, which is expressed in minutes offset from GMT.

Comment: my apologies for seeming dense, but I do not see how `set -o` connects with the offsets variable. On my machines, `set -o` returns `Environment variable -o not defined` and when stderr is redirected to nul it returns nothing.

Comment: @Paul - It only reports offset variables that are defined - none are defined by default. To get the time 2 hours ago, you could use `getTimestamp -oh -2`, and it would set `-oh=-2`, and `set -o` would report it. Offsets can be combined. For example, the minute offset (-om) and the day offset (-od) may be set independently. The offset variables are only defined during the execution of the script.

Comment: What a "neat" trick. I suppose it is a few characters shorter than `set|grep ^-o` if one is concerned about things like that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This works, there is no need for the type nul pipe.

```
wmic os get localdatetime | findstr .
```