# How to include hostname and date in output filename?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wmi-query

I have a batch file that gets installed software and updates.  It looks like this:

```
call wmic /output:"ServerName-InstalledSoftware-MMDDYYYY.csv" qfe get /format:csv
```

Every time I run this from a server, I have to modify the batch file with the current server and the date.

Is there a way that I can convert this to a VBScript file that grabs the `%computername%` variable and the `MMDDYYYY` date values automatically?

Answer (score 1):

From memory, this echos the MMDDYYY part (in separate lines)

```
echo %DATE:~4,2%
echo %DATE:~7,2%
echo %DATE:~-4%
```

and this will give you the servername:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

So your command should be

```
call wmic /output:"%COMPUTERNAME%-InstalledSoftware-%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~-4%.csv" qfe get /format:csv
```

You can try this out by substituting echo for call wmic /output:

```
echo "%COMPUTERNAME%-InstalledSoftware-%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~-4%.csv"
```

Comment: It might be simpler to just remove the separators in the date string: `%DATE:/=%`.

Comment: Good remark. Keep in mind that separators are locale dependent (order of dd, mm, yyyy also, so my code is not perfect either). When you want to have a version that runs on all versions of Windows, all languages, all locales, there is some more work to do. :-)

Comment: True, but his particular order (month before day) suggests US locale, so I'd consider `/` a safe guess in this case. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Assuming '/' or anything else would not be reliable in all locales. Using `wmic` will provide a standard result, but it introduces issues of its own. You might want to look at dbendham's getTimeStamp.bat script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034354/wmic-failure-with-concurrent-calls-on-xp-and-server-2003

Comment: @Paul I've seen Dave's script years ago and it's given me nightmares. ;þ If you need to deal with dates: stay away from batch files. *Far* away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in VBScript you'd do it in VBScript entirely:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

today = Right("00" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("00" & Day(Date), 2) & Year(Date)

filename = net.ComputerName & "-InstalledSoftware-" & today & ".csv"
dir      = "C:\output\folder"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.BuildPath(dir, filename), 2, True)

f.WriteLine "Node,Caption,CSName,Description,FixComments,HotFixID,InstallDate," & _
            "InstalledBy,InstalledOn,Name,ServicePackInEffect,Status"

For Each qf In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering")
  f.WriteLine net.ComputerName & _
    "," & qf.Caption & _
    "," & qf.CSName & _
    "," & qf.Description & _
    "," & qf.FixComments & _
    "," & qf.HotFixID & _
    "," & qf.InstallDate & _
    "," & qf.InstalledBy & _
    "," & qf.InstalledOn & _
    "," & qf.Name & _
    "," & qf.ServicePackInEffect & _
    "," & qf.Status
Next

f.Close
```

I'd recommend changing the date format to an ISO date format, though, so your files will be automatically in the correct date order:

```
today = Year(Date) & Right("00" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("00" & Day(Date), 2)
```