# Windows Batch: get current date and time within a loop

Tags: batch-file

The following will print the current data and time within a windows batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5,6 usebackq delims=:/ " %%a in ('%date% %time%') do echo %%c-%%a-%%b %%d%%e
```

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us).

However, if placed within a loop, the initial data and time will get continually printed, and will not be updated to reflect the new time.

How can it be modified to reflect the current time and work within a loop?

Thanks

Comment: ... another one. See the [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thanks very much. But its not clear to me, in the line above, what to change from %% or % to !.

Comment: `%%a`,...`%%e` are your `for`-variables. Don't change them. Use `!time!` instead of `%time%` (and `!date!`instead of `%date%` - just in case, your script runs about midnight ;)). But you will find a better way for Date-Time-string [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Comment: Be careful because this will probably not work with Windows in a different locale (where date and time are formatted differently)

Comment: I have had success using dbenham's getTimeStamp.bat script.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034354/wmic-failure-with-concurrent-calls-on-xp-and-server-2003

Comment: never use `%date%` for getting the date. It's unreliable because it depends on the current locale and datetime setting. See [How to get Windows batch date stamp that is locale independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56165593/995714)

Answer (score 0):

This is to be placed in a batch file or the code will not work.

`@echo off`

`:loop`

`echo date: %date% | time: %time%`

`goto loop`

Comment: Remove " | " and you wish!

Comment: I do test my code But I see what I missed

Comment: it doesn't. Remove the `|` or escape it: `^|`

Comment: what i mean is just do this `echo date:%Date% Time:%time%`

Comment: then edit your answer accordingly. Non-working answers tend to be downvoted and closed.